# Several duplicate Minecraft skin questions

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, specific-question

I noticed the other day that we have several (seven to be exact) questions asking about Minecraft skins not updating. Normally, I'd just cast duplicate votes on all of them, but since there are seven of them, and the consensus on "is time the most important thing when deciding which way to duplicate" is pretty much [up in the air](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8188/on-ending-chronological-oppression-with-respect-to-the-matter-of-question-duplic), I don't want to just start casting votes and then ask questions later.

Here are the seven questions, sorted from oldest to newest.

1. [My Custom Skin won't Change](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119939/my-custom-skin-wont-change)
2. [Minecraft skin is the same on LAN networks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122953/minecraft-skin-is-the-same-on-lan-networks)
3. [Why won't my new skin load?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142513/why-wont-my-new-skin-load)
4. [I need help with my minecraft skin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/176458/i-need-help-with-my-minecraft-skin)
5. [My minecraft skin wont load up in games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178263/my-minecraft-skin-wont-load-up-in-games)
6. [My Minecraft skin won't show for others](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188110/my-minecraft-skin-wont-show-for-others)
7. [My skin changes back to default when I join mini-games in servers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193690/my-skin-changes-back-to-default-when-i-join-mini-games-in-servers)

I feel that the first is a good candidate, since it is the oldest and has a decent answer. The third one is also a good candidate for duplication. But, like I said, I don't just want to cast votes when there's this many votes to be cast.

Comment: Would a Minecraft FAQ be too far out of the question? Eg. Like Memor-X's [Minecraft Crash FAQ](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/how-do-i-ask-minecraft-questions/10103#10103)

Comment: Duplicated questions can then be 'merged', and have all the answers merged into the final one, so I'd say pick the best worded/most viewed question and dupe the rest off that...

Comment: @Ben technically that answer (or even multiple answer) should cover more than just your crashes since the question title is *"How do I ask Minecraft Questions?"* thus the general knowledge stuff at the bottom, it just that i've seen more crash related question with problems and there's more than one Meta answer which could help improve quality. ofcause which ever question in the list above is used as the landing for duplicates then we can add it to the *"Some commonly asked and answered questions are"* list in the General part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and duplicated them to the oldest one. It seemed like the most appropriate action to take and 4 other users agreed with me in all cases. Case closed.