# Skyrim 'follower not wearing armor' question dupe closure should probably be the other way around

Tags: discussion, closing, exact-duplicates

RE: [My companion won't wear her armor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36994/4797) (2011-11-18) and [My housecarls won't stay dressed!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/47071/4797) (2012-01-15)

The former, older question has recently been closed as a duplicate of the latter. Now as per '[On ending Chronological Oppression with respect to the matter of Question Duplication](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8188/4797)', we could indeed close an older question as a duplicate of a newer one if the older question or its answers are of lower quality than the newer one, but I don't think that is the case here. The older question already had a couple good and upvoted answers before the newer question was posted, and its top-voted answer has more upvotes than its counterpart in the newer question.

Should we keep the duplicate closure or should it be closed the other way around?

Comment: The asker of the current duped one is the accepted answerer of the other one

Comment: Honestly, after reading both questions, I'm not even 100% convinced that it's the same issue. (One question is about followers sticking to their default armor, the other is about them going naked.) If both issues really have the same cause, they really need a definitive answer explaining the actual cause and how it manifests under different circumstances. (I'd bet that somebody's reverse-engineered the way followers select their equipment by now.) If not, the closed question should be reopened.

Comment: @Aequitas Interestingly enough the asker of the later question was also one of the voters to close the newer one. Oh, wait - that's me! I totally didn't realize until now that the question was older. I just came across it while I was browsing and was like, "this seems familiar". Didn't even realize the guy asking it had been the answerer I'd accepted on mine.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I believe the accepted answer to the newer question fairly well explains why they're likely the same issue and, as Aequitas has noted, even comes from the asker of the older question. It's very plausible that the same logic which prevents NPCs from choosing certain types of armor over others also keeps them from choosing the same armor types over none at all. Just like you'd probably never consider eating feces even if it was the only "edible" thing available to you after weeks of starvation.