# Handling these duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

This question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273283/pokemon-keep-running-away-and-pokestops-dont-drop-anything-when-spinning-what) asks about not being able to catch Pokémon anymore (they all flee) and not being able to collect anything from PokéStops anymore, and was closed as being too broad which I don't agree with (incidentally it has 4 reopen votes). [This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274315/why-cant-i-catch-pokemon-in-pokemon-go-anymore) question was then asked which asks the same thing got several good answers, one which is the same as was posted on the original question, and has several votes to close it as a duplicate of the original question. However, as it was not closed, it now has several other questions closed as duplicates of it.

The original question also has several questions closed as duplicates of it which leads to having several questions closed as a duplicate of one question, and several closed as a duplicate to another question which are both duplicates. This doesn't really help people that much if they happen to run into the set of questions duped to the "too broad" question as they will get a question that isn't as good and doesn't have as good of answers. So can we get the original question duped to the second question, and the questions duped to the original question get their dupe targets changed to the second question, as the second question is [better quality](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8188/on-ending-chronological-oppression-with-respect-to-the-matter-of-question-duplic)?

UPDATE:
The original question is now reopened, and has these as duplicates ([1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275695/pok%C3%A9mon-go-pok%C3%A9mon-escaping?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276813/why-does-every-single-pokemon-run-away-or-what-is-a-soft-ban?noredirect=1&lq=1), [3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276549/i-am-playing-pokemon-go-but-suddenly-i-cant-catch-any-pokemon?noredirect=1&lq=1), [4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276810/pokemon-always-flee-when-i-try-catching?noredirect=1&lq=1), [5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277253/pok%C3%A9mon-go-glitch?noredirect=1&lq=1), [6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276967/pokemon-go-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1), [7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277653/completely-broken-game-cant-play-anymore-please-help-pokemon-go)). The second question has these duplicates ([1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276967/pokemon-go-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273569/why-cant-i-catch-any-pok%C3%A9mon-in-pok%C3%A9mon-go?noredirect=1&lq=1), [3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274417/cant-catch-pok%C3%A9mon?noredirect=1&lq=1), [4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277716/pokemon-go-difficulties?noredirect=1&lq=1)). There is also a [third question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276221/not-getting-any-items-pokeballs-or-anything-else-at-poke-stops?noredirect=1&lq=1) that both of these two questions have been marked as a duplicate of. Now, if you haven't gotten confused yet, I have just trying to figure out how all of these were linked. Obviously, this is not an ideal situation, so can we pick the best question of the three that are open, and dupe everything to that, and maybe clean up some of the duplicates (this will need a mods intervention at this point)? I vote to close everything as a dupe of the second question.

UPDATE 2:
The third question has now been marked as a duplicate of both the first two, and the second question has been marked as a duplicate of the first one (partially due to me forgetting to retract my close vote). I personally think that it should be duped the other way around as the second question is a better question than the first, but regardless which question is chosen to be the main dupe target, the questions marked as duplicates of the other need to have their dupe path updated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I merged the old question into the new question. Now we have all the answers from both on a single, better-worded question.

Comment: This seems like it works and makes everything nice.