# How to ask for updates on questions that don't include DLC?

Tags: discussion

Answers to this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/338700/what-attacks-can-i-block-with-the-guard-up-skill-that-i-normally-coudnt) cover the base game Monster Hunter World. I would like to know how the list changes/expands with Monster Hunter World: Iceborne.

**How would I ask for an update of this list?**

Possible options:

1. Update the existing question (add tag [monster-hunter-world-iceborne]; expand question; comment on answer to request update)
2. Create a new question asking only for the [monster-hunter-world-iceborne] list

My concerns:

Option 1 couldn't be okay as the original question did not intend to ask for Iceborne. Therefore it could be vandalism or whatever (not sure though).

Option 2 doesn't seem to be okay in regard to these meta questions:

- [Handling Dupes Asking For Updated Info](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/handling-dupes-asking-for-updated-info)
- [Are Questions Asking For Updated Info Duplicates?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12637/are-questions-asking-for-updated-info-duplicates)

Comment: This seems to be a more specific case of the "outdated question or answer" issue that Arqade has been encountering since... forever, essentially. I have not seen a solution that most of the community agreed with, and I'm not sure there will ever be one.

Comment: On its own the answer to the question as it is is not outdated IMO. The question was asked for the base game and the answer fits perfectly for the base game. And for people who are only playing the base game, it is not outdated as well. Maybe a question specifically for Iceborn with a link to the base game question would be appropriate?

Comment: I am not sure about the site mechanics, but could you ask for another question with the DLC specific tag e.g. Iceborne. And mods/high-rep users could merge the two questions?

Comment: I'm sure the answer could be handled in a similar manner on how Wrigglenite handles his amazing answer on [catching rare pets](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/326201/what-are-the-locations-and-conditions-for-catching-the-rare-pets). Originally asked/answered for the base game, but he expanded on his answer to include Iceborne content.

Comment: In that case it would mean to update the question to be asked for the DLC as well (adding the appropriate tag) and asking for an update on the answer. But then again, this would invalidate the answer if it is not updated. And that would be wrong IMO

Answer (score 1):

In the case of DLC, I think it is better to update the old answer with an additional section.  Most DLCs are not substantive enough to get their own tags like Iceborne, since most of them only add a few extra hours of content.  There is no issue with using the Iceborne tag to ask an Iceborne specific question but in this specific case, it is best to update the existing answer with the DLC information.

Patches, on the other hand, are a much trickier situation.  Games like Minecraft (sandbox games) or Warcraft 3 have patch specific info that is useful at all times since it is occasionally desirable by users to play on a specific patch.  If the patch info is not included in the post and another question is asked with version specific information required, I think both questions should remain open and all answers should be preserved.  It is my personal opinion that this information is equally useful but the general community may feel otherwise.

On the issue of reopening old questions, I do not feel that reopened questions get as much attention as newer questions.  I also believe that adding additional answers to already answered questions every time a patch hits would make certain questions too cluttered.  Most users probably will not scroll past the accepted answer and will only get the outdated information.  It is for this reason, the community has to decide if they want to maintain historical patch data which comes with more cluttered answers or additional questions opened on the same topic, or removing historical data which leaves us with fewer questions and less clutter but removes an excellent resource for hard to find data.

The most optimal solution, in my opinion, is an added tab in questions for questions that have completely outdated information.  There are questions that have info that is completely inapplicable to the current game and will never be applicable again.  A good example of this kind of question is something like this [CSGO Case Drop Rates](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270753/csgo-case-drop-limit?noredirect=1&lq=1).  Currently, I find I can only get 1 case drop per week and even if you did find a way to play an old patch, you probably would be unable to get drops since they are so closely tied with steam accounts.  If you look through the linked and related questions, there are many outdated answers still open with info from previous operations, patches, etc.

With this feature, the community would have to vote a question into this category and approved by a high rep user.  The current answer would be left behind and maybe given an edit to mark that it was the previous answer.  This way you could get standard rep for answering a question, draw attention to outdated questions better, removes clutter/additional questions, and generally, incentivizes users to interact with old questions.

Comment: `it is better to update the old answer with an additional section` -> but how would one go about it? Would I update the existing question and ask the answerers to update their answer? This would make the answers incomplete unless updated. And you can't force users to update answers. Also an updated question does not get as much traction as a new question (IMO). That would mean that a new answer containing all the information is less likely to be given. Also how would the incomplete answers be handled? They were once complete (and maybe accepted) but are no longer

Comment: In this case, the scope of the question is essentially the same: What can I block that was previously unblockable?  The old question is correctly answered but since (in theory) a user should look up their question to see if somebody has asked it before, they should find that the question has not been answered for iceborne.  If they decide to ask a question and it is closed as a dupe, it draws attention to the old question.  The community can then propose edits to the correct answers.  It either has to work like this or not mark DLC questions as dupes and let them be linked.

Comment: The question is the same, but not the scope (basegame vs. DLC). I think the cleanest solution without invalidating any question/answer, would be to ask the question specifically for the DLC and link both questions. This way, no question/answer  would be invalidated while also having a direct link between them in case a user is only interested in basegame or DLC. This would also prevent clustering of the answers (I personally find Wrigglenite's [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/326201/what-are-the-locations-and-conditions-for-catching-the-rare-pets) hard to read)

Comment: I think that is the best solution with what we currently have but seems to go against the wishes of the community.  People have a pretty itchy trigger finger to close questions as dupes in my opinion...