# Question reopen request and question on how to properly take action on similar issues

Tags: discussion, closing

I've found a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/356075/how-do-i-use-tellraw-selectors-on-bedrock-edition) on Arqade that has been closed as a duplicate of another.

I do not believe that this question is a duplicate of its current duplicate target. It can be inferred in two ways, one that renders it as a duplicate, and another way that renders it as a separate question.

- **Duplicate inference:** The question refers to outputting a selector to chat using a command block, which has already been asked.
- **Non-duplicate inference:** The question refers to using `/tellraw`, while the duplicate target has an accepted answer of using `/say`, and `/tellraw` is different from `/say`.

It is currently unclear about which intent the OP had on this question. However, I have the same question of the *Non-duplicate inference* and would like an answer.

What is the best course of action? Here are the options I've considered:

- Starting a bounty on the original, saying that there needs to be another answer on `/tellraw.`
- Requesting for the duplicate to be reopened here as if it is the *Non-duplicate inference* I mentioned earlier. (if this is the best action, treat this as my reopen request)
- Editing the duplicate to clarify it as the *Non-duplicate inference*, and getting it reopened so.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think reopening the old question makes any sense, as the user hasn't been active in over a year.

I'm not a Minecraft expert, so I could be off base here, but I think the best course of action is for you to just ask a whole new question. We could then edit the closure text for [How do I use Tellraw Selectors on Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/356075/how-do-i-use-tellraw-selectors-on-bedrock-edition) to point to both it's current duplicate  target and [your new question.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8188/on-ending-chronological-oppression-with-respect-to-the-matter-of-question-duplic)

If you do ask a new question, I think it would be a good idea to explain why  you want to use `/tellraw` instead of `/say`.

Comment: I have updated a similar question to include the scope of the one in question here. Please view my [new question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/370567/250180) using the link.